# media player error : error (260, -2147483648)

Tags: android, media

When i play a video with media player, it work fine util i change orientation , my media player throw error (260, -2147483648).
I've search about this error but no result.
So what is that?

Here is my logcat when i change orientation:

```
04-15 15:23:04.371: E/androidEx2 = VideoSample(6358): surfaceDestroyed
04-15 15:23:04.391: E/androidEx2 = VideoSample(6358): onTrackPause
04-15 15:23:04.575: E/androidEx2 = VideoSample(6358): surfaceCreated
04-15 15:23:04.576: E/androidEx2 = VideoSample(6358): onTrackStart
04-15 15:23:04.576: E/androidEx2 = VideoSample(6358): VIDEO SIZES: W: 640 H: 360 PROP: 1.7777778
04-15 15:24:43.643: E/androidEx2 = VideoSample(6358): VIDEO SIZES: W: 800 H: 480 PROP: 1.6666666
04-15 15:24:43.678: E/MediaPlayer(6358): error (260, -2147483648)
04-15 15:24:43.801: E/MediaPlayer(6358): Error (260,-2147483648)
04-15 15:24:44.301: E/MediaPlayer(6358): stop called in state 0
04-15 15:24:44.301: E/MediaPlayer(6358): error (-38, 0)
04-15 15:24:44.341: E/androidEx2 = VideoSample(6358): onTrackStop
```

Comment: Can you please post your code and logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

register your activity with this attribute

```
<activity
    android:configChange="orientation|screenSize"
/>
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`

If you want to set your screen in specific orientation like in landscape only then use this attribute in `<activity>`

```
<activity
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
/>
```

Comment: Oh, awesome!!!!!!!!, i miss config screensize, thanks you so much. I'm so stupid . But What the error in my question mean?